# The breakpoint doesn't met when implementing an interface

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I have the following interfaces

```cpp
template <typename string_t>
class PluginManager
{
public:
  virtual ~PluginManager() = default;
  virtual Plugin<string_t>* findPlugin(string_t const&plugin_uuid) const = 0;
  virtual Plugin<string_t>* loadPlugin(string_t const&plugin) = 0;
  virtual void unloadPlugin(string_t const&plugin) = 0;
  virtual void registerPlugin(Plugin<string_t> *plugin) = 0;
  virtual void unregisterPlugin(Plugin<string_t> *plugin) = 0;
  virtual void sigPluginLoaded() = 0;
};

template <typename string_t>
class Plugin
{
public:
  virtual ~Plugin() = default;
  virtual string_t uuid() const = 0;
  virtual void setManager(PluginManager<string_t> *manager) = 0;
};
```

I also have two classes that implement these interfaces

```cpp
class Core : public QObject, public PluginManager<QString>
{
  Q_OBJECT
  using string_t = QString;
  using map_t = QMap<string_t, ad::Plugin<string_t>*>;
private:
  Core();
public:
  static Core* instance();
  Plugin<string_t>* findPlugin(string_t const&plugin_uuid) const override;
  Plugin<string_t>* loadPlugin(string_t const&plugin) override;
  void unloadPlugin(string_t const&plugin) override;
  void registerPlugin(Plugin<string_t> *plugin) override;
  void unregisterPlugin(Plugin<string_t> *plugin) override;
signals:
  void sigPluginLoaded();
private:
  map_t __plugin_map;
  static Core* __instance;
};

class SettingsApplierPlugin : public QObject, public ad::Plugin<QString>
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  SettingsApplierPlugin();
  QString uuid() const override;
  void setManager(ad::PluginManager<QString> *manager) override;
public slots:
  void updateSettings() const;
private:
  PluginManager<QString> *__plg_mgr;
};
```

And finally the function implementation that neccessary for this question

```cpp
void Core::registerPlugin(ad::Plugin<Core::string_t> *plugin)
{
  plugin->setManager(this);
  __plugin_map.insert(plugin->uuid(), plugin);
  emit sigPluginLoaded();
}
```

#### The problem

When I debug the code (I use VSCode with gdb 8.2.91 and Ubuntu 19.04) it behaves strangely. When I step into the `plugin->setManager(this)` (the plugin in this point is an instance of class `SettingsApplierPlugin`) the debugger shows the line of the declaration of that class and after one more step-into, it shows the line of the destructor of the Plugin class.

#### Notice

The image changes, when I remove the `QObject` class from bases of `SettingsApplierPlugin` and the `Q_OBJECT` macro from the class definition, everything works fine and debugger enters into the function correctly.

#### Note 1

The `class SettingsApplierPlugin` comes from a shared library and the `class Core` comes from another shared library.

#### Note 2

All `string_t`s are typedefs -> `using string_t = QString`.

#### My restrictions

I want to derive from `QObject` because I want to use the provided `signal-slot` mechanism.

### The question

Can anybody explain the behavior and suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: are all the shared libraries built in debug?

Comment: Did you mean if they build using `debug` configuration? Yes.